# Check default ion-radio using ngIf

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to check an ion radio using the value comparison with `*ngIf`. I displayed my ion radio value dynamically with `*ngFor`.

Here is what I've got in my html side :

```
<ion-list radio-group *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <div *ngIf="category.id === 1">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{ category.category_title }}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio [checked]="true" value="{{ category.id }}" (ionSelect)="selectedCategory(category.id)"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="category.id !== 1">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{ category.category_title }}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio [checked]="false" value="{{ category.id }}" (ionSelect)="selectedCategory(category.id)"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

Based on the coding above, I use `*ngIf="category.id === 1"` to check if the ion radio value is `1` then the ion radio should be check true else it will remain false. I checked from other people's post as well and I tried to apply it in my code but it does not work. I'm not really sure how is the if else working in angular.

**EDIT**

From component side :

```
categories = [];

getCategories(){
    this.http.get(this.restProvider.restApiUrl+'practice/getCategory').map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.categories = data.categories;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `[value]` instead of `value`

```
<ion-list radio-group *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <div *ngIf="category.id === '1'">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{ category.category_title }}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio [checked]="true" [value]="category.id" (ionSelect)="selectedCategory(category.id)"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="category.id !== '1'">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{ category.category_title }}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio [checked]="false" [value]="category.id" (ionSelect)="selectedCategory(category.id)"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use `[value]` instead of `value` it will throw me an error `Template parse errors`

Comment: you sure? I created a stackblitz for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/ion-radio-list-example-baxbqf

Comment: Yeah it's actually working. I just did some mistake when applying it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry can I ask another question? How should I change the selected radio based on user select? Because it currently allowing to select all.

Comment: Check it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ion-radio-list-example-baxbqf?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html, I added `[(ngModel)]` hope it helps you.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your **`category.id`** is a string, so you should enclose within **`''`**

```
<div *ngIf="category.id === '1'">
```

Comment: My categories result is this `{"categories": [{ "id": "5", "category_title": "Category 1" }]}`

Comment: I've tried to enclose with quote but it's still not working.

Comment: can you post your component.ts also

Comment: the code looks correct , btw did you add a '' to the else part as well?

Comment: Yes I've added both.

Comment: you should use [value] , but the answer to the initial question was my answer